# Solidres appearance

Tags: php, joomla

[image: Module's appearance]

I have been testing solidres using not less than five Joomla templates, including [Firefly](http://demo.themexpert.com/joomla/firefly), [JA_Brickstore](http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#ja_brickstore) etc
but each of those displays the module improperly. Can any one please help on how to to make it look better?

Comment: A link to the live website might help. E.g. Could bootstrap be conflicting with the template styling?

Comment: The site is on my localhost and the module is responding well with inbuilt templates as opposed to third party ones

Comment: Then try using FireBug or similar to check why the height of those date fields is too small. You should be able to see which CSS file is causing this and maybe this will be a clue to solving the issue. It's not likely anyone else can solve it without being able to see some code.

Comment: There are two options: 1). Overriding CSS - "/templates/my_template_name/css/com_solidres/assets/main.min.css"  2). Changing CSS -  "/media/com_solidres/assets/css/main.min.css" and it works. Thanks @NeilRobertson for your ideas/suggestions.